# Perform Tile Index on Newly Created PDFs using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, algorithm, geospatial-pdf

The python code below successfully performs the `tile index` algorithm on all PDF files stored in sub-folders named `!pdf's` within my `V:Drive`. A list of all paths to each PDF exported from QGIS is created first off, then a processing loop is performed against the variable `pdf_path`. The output is created as a `.gpkg`.

```
import os
import pathlib

my_path = "V:/GIS - Files/1. Client Projects/"
pdf_parent_folder = "!pdf's"
pdf_paths = []

for path, sub, files in os.walk(my_path):
    if pdf_parent_folder in sub:
        for path, sub, files in os.walk(os.path.join(path, pdf_parent_folder)):
            for name in files:
                if os.path.splitext(name)[1] == ".pdf":
                    pdf_paths.append(str(pathlib.PurePath(path, name)))

print(pdf_paths)

out_file = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Example_Folder\\Output_file.gpkg'#             
change to your own file path
for pdf_path in pdf_paths:
    processing.run('gdal:tileindex',
                {'ABSOLUTE_PATH': True,
                'LAYERS': pdf_path,
                'OUTPUT': out_file})
```

As a one-off this is perfect however, at the end of each working week, I would like to add the tile index of the new PDFs I export to the `.gpkg` output.

Is there a time constraint I can add to prevent the algorithm inputting PDFs I already have tile indexes for?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way but this should work on Windows:

```
#print(pdf_paths)
import datetime
week_start = datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 14, 8, 30) #Y, M, D, H, M (example returns: 2019-10-14 08:30:00)
out_file = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Example_Folder\\Output_file.gpkg'#change to your own file path
for pdf_path in pdf_paths:
    path_ctime = os.path.getctime(pdf_path) #get creation time of each path
    created_at = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(path_ctime)
    if created_at > week_start:
        processing.run('gdal:tileindex',
                    {'ABSOLUTE_PATH': True,
                    'LAYERS': pdf_path,
                    'OUTPUT': out_file})
```

- Import the `datetime` module
- Specify the starting time e.g. the start of the working week as a datetime object
- use `getctime()` to get the creation time for each pdf path in the list and convert it to a datetime object for evaluation.
- Evaluate each filepath creation time against the starting time of working week and, only if the creation time is later than the starting time, run the tile index algorithm.

Comment: Hi Ben, apologies I got tied up with other things before being able to test this. I have trialled this out by editing the script week_start to today (2019,11,11). I have exported only one PDF today however multiple PDFs are indexed. There is obviously no error in the code but the start date doesn't seem to be taken into account. Additionally, is it as simple as adding 'week_end = date....' to create a date range?

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure it was working for me when I posted the answer. I will try to test it again tomorrow if I get a chance.

Comment: @James B, I have tested this script and it is working fine for me... I'm not sure why it is not for you. In the absence of any error messages, all I can suggest is to try and debug by adding some print statements to check what is returned by the various objects like `week_start`; then `path_ctime` and `created_at` in the for loop. This may reveal where the problem lies.